# How can I get more room in my inventory?

Tags: starbound

I'm tired of making trips back to my ship to offload materials when my inventory starts getting full. It looks like you start the game with one bag for items and another bag for the materials you mine such as dirt, cobblestone, etc, though it also appears that other than the game automatically choosing which bag to dumps something in, you can use the bags interchangeably (i.e., I can put a laser pistol in my material bag, if I want).

Is there any way, though, to get more bags or otherwise expand the size of my inventory? The current inventory screen looks like it has room for more, but I haven't found any yet.

[image]

Comment: You can always get rid of things you don't want by throwing them away. I only really keep ores food and tools. I've only ever run into problems looting decorative stuff from new dungeons.

Comment: @Katustrawfic that doesn't answer the question - Sterno is clearly a hoarder :o)

Comment: I believe that the special Iron Armor for humans provides additional storage slots, but I cannot confirm this personally.  As for the...brown dirt option you have there, you can store anything you like over in that storage space, even non-dirt items, and the game won't mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is currently no way to increase inventory space, although, since this is still beta, I would expect this to change. But the current answer is no, those two bags are all you have. Obviously, once this changes, I will attempt to remember to come back and edit this answer.

Comment: As far as I can tell in 1.0 stable there is still no way to increase your inventory. They did split the inventory into more categories (tabs) so it is tidier and roomier, but there is still no way to increase the number of slots

Answer (score 0):

Backpacks are already in the game, but not working yet, even though they already say "Increase your storage space" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Not Currently.

However, if you do run into storage problems and are a hoarder (like me), then I would suggest find chests and place them on your ships and put your stuff in them.

Also fill up your ship locker. Then when the time is right, use them to decorate and make awesome bases :)